# Random and unique number generation process in php

Tags: php

please check below example for better explanation.

In form i have below fields

### Example :

Account creation count : 300
Account prefix : 123 (value depend on user)
Account Length : 4 (value depend on user)

Here length of Account Prefix is 3 and account length is 4 
4-3 =1

Here we get 1 
if we create random characters between 0-9 =10 and a-z =26 so total is 36
user can create maximum 36 accounts with this prefix.

But i want also check in database any number already with this prefix and random number

Like 
i get random single digit is "D" then execute query like

> select id from table where length(number) =4 and number like '123d'

if already exist in database then need to create another random character.

I am using currently below function but its going to infinite loop.

### CODE :

```
function find_uniq_rendno_accno($length = '1', $field = '', $tablename = '',$prefix) {
    $key = '';
    $keys = array_merge(range(0, 9), range('a', 'z'));

    for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
        $key .= $keys[array_rand($keys)];
    }
     $where = array($field => $default.$string);
     $acc_result = $this->CI->db_model->getSelect('Count(id) as count', $tablename, $where);
    while ($acc_result[0]['count'] != 0) {
      $key=  $this->find_uniq_rendno_accno($length, $field, $tablename,$default);
    }
    return $key;
    }
```

Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `while` statement's condition makes this function infinitely recursive. If `$acc_result[0]['count']` is unequal to zero, it will be still after the recursive call in that loop terminates.

Comment: Thanks for reply, What changes i have to make in my functions which check in database for unique number. any better solution